# Mounting encrypted Samba share (linux server/client)

Tags: samba, linux-networking, mount, encryption, samba4

I'm trying to set up encrypted samba access. In order to achieve that I've added 2 lines to `[global]` scope in smb.conf:

```
server signing = mandatory
smb encrypt = mandatory
```

But unfortunately I can't mount samba shares now anywhere. I've tried with Dolphin under KDE and using mount -t cifs, even tried smbclient command line. I'm getting following errors:

dolphin:

`Unknown error condition in stat: Software caused connection abort`

mount:

`mount error(13): Permission denied`

smbclient:

`Error returning browse list: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED`

how to properly enforce encryption and mount it on linux machine? Windows would be nice as well but I've read that this encryption method is not supported there yet.

I have samba 4.1 on client and 3.6 on server (OpenSUSE / Debian) but tried also looped connection on SUSE 4.1 <> 4.1 with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, `mount.cifs` does not support the encryption feature of Samba (yet!?).

The `-e` option of `smbclient` should work, though.

Comment: I can verify that smbclient (using smbclient Version 4.5.6) works with transport-encrypted partitions.

Answer (score 1):

**mount.cifs** supports SMB3 encryption [since version 4.8.0-54.57](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1670508/comments/12) of Linux kernel.

So upgrade to the latest Linux kernel and voila!